# Group by clause with min

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I am having the following table

[image]

I used following query and i got error message. I can identify why the error is but how can i solve it

```
select min(id),customer_id,created_at from thunderbolt_orders
  group by customer_id
```

I need the minimum id's customer_id and created_at how can i achieve it.

Comment: What type of error you get?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group)

Comment: Is it just the lowest possible ID and it's customer_id and created_at or is it the lowest ID for each customer_id and then the information back

Answer (score 5):

```
select distinct on (customer_id)
    customer_id, id, created_at
from thunderbolt_orders
order by customer_id, id
```

Answer (score 2):

```
with cte as (
    select
        *, row_number() over(partition by customer_id order by id) as row_num
    from Table1
)
select *
from cte
where row_num = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id,customer_id,created_at 
       FROM thunderbolt_orders 
       WHERE id IN 
       (SELECT MIN(id) FROM thunderbolt_orders GROUP BY customer_id);
```

Comment: @NaveenKumar:- Have you check my edited answer? I think you are not, which i edited before your answer and comment.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether or not you just want the minimum ID or whether you want the minimum ID for each customer these are the solutions.

Minimum ID:

```
select top 1 id,customer_id,created_at from thunderbolt_orders order by id asc
```

Minimum ID for each customer:

```
with cte as (
    select min(id) as id
    from thunderbolt_orders 
    group by customer_id
)
select *
from cte c
inner join thunderbolt_orders t on t.id = c.id
```